# Set up FontAwesome icon in bash promt

Tags: command-line, bash, icons

I did everything from this tutorial [Trendy Bash shell prompt with fontawesome and PS1](https://www.pcsuggest.com/trendy-bash-shell-prompt-with-fontawesome-and-ps1/), Even set in Terminal > Profile Preferences > Custom font > FontAwesome and nothing, not one icon shows to me, when type `echo -e 'xefx80x87'` it just returns `xefx80x87` instead of icon. Any idea how set icon in terminal promt, I wanna set ubuntu icon intead of `username@hostname`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bug on that web page.

Where is says:  `echo -e 'xefx80x87'`
you really need: `echo -e '\xef\x80\x87'`